# How to execute mysql query reading from .sql file and exporting to .csv or .err using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, csv

I want to get the same result from a C# windows form button click as i get using this command:

```
mysql --host="example" --port="1111" --user="user" --password="pwd" --skip-column-names < report.sql > report.csv 2>report.err
```

So far i got this, i can enter a command (like dir of ipconfig) and get results. but when i enter a command that expects another value (like the password for mysql) the program freezes.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Crash_Report
{
public partial class masodik : Form
{
    private static StringBuilder cmdOutput = null;
    Process cmdProcess;
    StreamWriter cmdStreamWriter;

    public masodik()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private static void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess,
        DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
        {
            cmdOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
        }
    }

    private void exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmdStreamWriter.Close();
        cmdProcess.WaitForExit();
        cmdProcess.Close();
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmdStreamWriter.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void F5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = cmdOutput.ToString();
    }

    private void masodik_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmdOutput = new StringBuilder("");
        cmdProcess = new Process();

        cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        //cmdProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @" /k";
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

       // cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += new          DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
        cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += bejovo;

        cmdProcess.Start();
        cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        cmdStreamWriter = cmdProcess.StandardInput;

    }

    private void bejovo(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
           textBox2.AppendText(e.Data);
           textBox2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }    
}
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You should insert the SET command at beginning of report.sql.

Comment: its is there. the question is how can i launch a command line code from c#. my main problem is at the end of the line:
    < report.sql > report.csv 2>report.err